# Conditional hue for columns that are below mean

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the hue of a particular column (if below the mean):

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- read.table(text=" cars    trucks  suvs
1   2   4
3   5   4
6   4   6
4   5   6
9   12  16", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)
dat$day <- factor(c("Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr"), 
             levels=c("Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr"))

mdat <- melt(dat, id.vars="day")
head(mdat)
ggplot(mdat, aes(variable, value, fill=day)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
geom_line(stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean", aes(colour = day, group=day), size=1.5, linetype="dashed")
```

For example: column cars/Friday should be slightly lighter in color as it is below its mean:

[image: Plot]

Is it possible to do this in ggplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a identifier variable indicating whether the value is below the mean.

```
mdat$below.mean <- ave(mdat$value, mdat$day, FUN = function(x) x > mean(x))
```

this adds a logical integer column to the dataset where all the values which are above the mean are coded as `1` and the others as `0`:

```
> mdat
   day variable value below.mean
1   Mo     cars     1          0
2   Tu     cars     3          0
3   We     cars     6          1
4   Th     cars     4          0
5   Fr     cars     9          0
6   Mo   trucks     2          0
7   Tu   trucks     5          1
8   We   trucks     4          0
9   Th   trucks     5          0
10  Fr   trucks    12          0
11  Mo     suvs     4          1
12  Tu     suvs     4          0
13  We     suvs     6          1
14  Th     suvs     6          1
15  Fr     suvs    16          1
```

Now you can use that variable to make the bars which are below the mean lighter with the `alpha` parameter:

```
ggplot(mdat, aes(variable, value, fill=day, alpha=factor(below.mean))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5,1)) +
  guides(alpha=FALSE) +                        # this remove the 'alpha' legend
  theme_minimal()
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possible solution, building upon the one proposed by @Jaap:

I suggest using faceting to group `day` values together, so that visual comparison within `day` is easier. Also, I propose using the ColorBrewer "Paired" color scale.

```
# Borrowed from @Jaap. Add column indicating above and below mean for each day.
mdat$below.mean <- factor(ave(mdat$value, mdat$day,
                              FUN=function(x) ifelse(x > mean(x), "Above", "Below")),
                          levels=c("Below", "Above"))

# Create auxiliary data.frame for plotting mean lines.
mean_data = aggregate(value ~ day, data=mdat, FUN=mean)

# Using paired colors to indicate above and below mean.
p1 = ggplot(mdat, aes(variable, value, fill=below.mean, group=day)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity") +
     geom_hline(data=mean_data, aes(yintercept=value), linetype=3, size=1) +
     scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired", name="Below Mean") +
     theme_minimal() +
     facet_grid(. ~ day)

# Using 5 sets of paired colors, to show above and below mean for each day.
p2 = ggplot(mdat, aes(variable, value, fill=interaction(below.mean, day))) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity") +
     geom_hline(data=mean_data, aes(yintercept=value), linetype=3, size=1) +
     scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired", name="Below Mean") +
     theme_minimal() +
     facet_grid(. ~ day)


library(gridExtra)
ggsave("plots.png", plot=arrangeGrob(p1, p2, ncol=1), width=10, height=6, dpi=150)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice extended solution! +1